# Reminiscent of somebody

Tags: word-usage

Can we say

> You are reminiscent of your father

in order to refer to someone`s either psychical or characteristic resemblance of another person in the sense of  to remind?

or this sentence is more correct

> You are reminiscent of the way your father behave.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think "[reminiscent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reminiscent)" fit since it is very linked to memory and mental representation. It is coming from [reminiscence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reminiscence):

> An act of remembering long-past experiences, often fondly.
>
> A mental image thus remembered.

---

You may talk about "copy", "twin" or just say he behaves similarly if you want a strong image.

> You act like a copy of your father

If you prefer something more common, you can say :

> When you {act|smile} like this, **you look like your father** !

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask something else .Suppose someone's grandfather passed away so somebody who had very strong bond his grandfather says :  `your smile reminiscent of my grandfather`   or  I should stick to ` your smile remind me of  my grandfather`

Comment: @Murat I don't think "reminiscent" is often used and people may not understand why you use it. *"your smile remind me ..."* is perfect imho.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason,

- You are reminiscent of your father.

sounds much less natural than

- You remind me of your father.

Perhaps this is because the first is in passive tense, which makes it quite vague as to **who** might be doing the reminiscing.

Answer (score 0):

We normally say that "Something or someone is reminiscent of Y". We do not say "*You* are reminiscent of Y".  Why not?

To say that something or someone is reminiscent of Y is to say that the thing or the person would remind *anyone and everyone* of Y, which is not the same as saying "It reminds *me* of Y* or "She reminds *me* of Y" or "You remind me of Y".

The thing or person in question has characteristics so similar to Y that anyone would be reminded of Y. I (the speaker) am a person, so I am reminded of Y, true, but so would  *you* (my conversation partner or reader) be reminded, and so would the person-on-the-street be reminded.

It is the impersonal construction together with the direct address ("you") which makes the following sound odd:

**You are reminiscent of your father.**

You remind *a person* of your father. Since you, too, are a person, you would remind yourself of your father.